# Get "Could not open input file: composer.phar" when calling composer.phar in terminal

Tags: php, macos, terminal, composer-php

I am working on a PHP development project that includes Composer. I am relatively new at this so I thank you in advance for your patience with my question, and ask that you reply in as simple of language as possible.

I am trying to run the following command in terminal:

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

This is the file path to my composer.phar folder:
         /Users/administrator/Dropbox/2016/2016ProjectFiles/2016ProjectsWeb/GG/authentication/composer.phar

I have tried several ways to provide the file path, including the following:

```
$cd /Users/administrator/Dropbox/2016/2016ProjectFiles/2016ProjectsWeb/GG/authentication/composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

...and...

```
$cd ../authentication/composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

It is entirely possible/likely that my syntax is wrong or there is a stupid simple solution that I just don't know. I just need to be able to run file commands on composer.phar from terminal. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How did you install composer? What OS do you use? What is listed when you run `ls` or `ll` (show all files in the directory)? What happens when you try running `composer` only?

Comment: Hi, Tomas. Thank you for the quick reply.  I am running OSX El Capitan on a MacBook Pro. I used the download command on getcomposer.org

    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
    php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
    php composer-setup.php
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

Moved after install to FP above.

Comment: "What happens when you try running composer only?" IDK what is meant by this exactly. I would need to you write out the command line and I will give it a try.

Comment: Just run: `composer`

Comment: When I run "Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ administrator$ composer" it returns "-bash: composer: command not found"  // when I run "Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ administrator$ php composer" it returns "Could not open input file: composer"

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded `composer.phar` file successfully. Great job. Now the second steps is to make ti globally accessible like `php` or `git`.

[This article about installing composer in Mac](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/installing-composer-on-os-x) describe as follows:

### Quoting *Running Composer* section

Run commads:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Now add to `.bash_profile`:

```
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

And you're done.

Run `composer` anywhere you need.

Comment: Thank you, Tomas. I think maybe my original question was misunderstood. I have already successfully installed composer. What I am trying to do is run the "php composer.phar dump-autoload -o" command in terminal. It is saying that it cannot find composer.phar which IS already properly installed. I have moved the composer files to a different directory on my computer which I suspect is why terminal is not finding it where it thinks it should. I need to somehow tell terminal where composer is so that it can run the  "dump-autoload" process.

Comment: Composer is not properly installed. It is only downloaded. 2nd step of installation is to make it globally available. Like `php` or `git` commands are.  You don't use `cd` commands to get directory with `php` file binnary, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the answer in case any fellow newbies run into this same conundrum. First, enter the following command into terminal to tell it where to look for Composer:

```
     cd ~/[YOUR FOLDER NAME]
```

I learned that "~/" is a stand in for your "Users/Username" folders, so if your version of composer is nested beyond that you'll have to write out the file path yourself. For example, if your file is in "Dropbox" in a folder called "Projects" then your first command would look like this...

```
    cd ~/Dropbox/Projects/[YOUR FOLDER NAME]
```

Then, you'll see your terminal command line change. For example, before I ran the command above, mine looked like...

```
    Admin-MacBook-Pro:~ administrator$
```

...afterward it looked like...

```
    Admin-MacBook-Pro:authentication administrator$
```

"authentication" is the folder where I saved Composer. YAY! So then I was able to type in my request:

```
    php composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

And it (finally!) returned "Generating optimized autoload files". So there you have it. I hope I saved you a couple of hours staring at the terminal window.

Thank you, [Tomáš Votruba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348344/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-votruba) for your suggestions!

Comment: Great job. You still need to add `composer` to your PATH. These steps you describe are redundant and make using composer unnecessary complicated.

Comment: I've updated the answer, so it's more clear. You don't need to read whole article, just last headline.